# Transfer File from on prem to sharepoint online

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am working a file transfer script using Sharepoint online pnp with the below script

```
#Set up variables to fetch data
$SiteURL = "https://demo.sharepoint.com/sites/ssup"
$TargetFolderURL = "/Shared Documents/FileDemo/FilesFromX"

$FilestoLoadToSPO = Get-ChildItem -Path \\Demo_FileTransfer\FilesToSPO  -Filter '*.txt' 
#results with listing 2 files.

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteurl -UseWebLogin


Foreach ($file in $FilestoLoadToSPO ) {
    Add-PnPFile -Path $file -Folder $TargetFolderURL
}
```

I get the following error. any help will be appreciated.

```
Add-PnPFile : Local file was not found.
At line:14 char:5
+     Add-PnPFile -Path $file -Folder $TargetFolderURL
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPFile], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.AddFile


Add-PnPFile : Local file was not found.
At line:14 char:5
+     Add-PnPFile -Path $file -Folder $TargetFolderURL

    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPFile], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.AddFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7) returns *objects*, not paths. If you pass `$file` to Add-PnPFile, it will be converted to string, but the result will be only the file name, not the full path. (Try yourself: `$file.ToString()`)

Specify the full path using the `FullName` property, like this:

```
Add-PnPFile -Path $file.FullName -Folder $TargetFolderURL
```